# Selector on Android sockets behaves strangely

Tags: java, android, nio

Prerequisites: Android 2.2 emulator.

I have a perfectly working Java code which is compiled perfectly for Android as well. But there comes the strange part. In particular, it seems that java.nio.Selector doesn't work at all.

First problem arises during connection. The following code works on Java but doesn't work on Android (see below for details).

```
socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(remoteAddr, getRemotePort()));

Selector selector = Selector.open();
socketChannel.register(selector, socketChannel.validOps());

// Wait for an event
int selRes = selector.select(timeout); 
if (selRes == 1)
{
    SelectionKey selKey = (SelectionKey)selector.selectedKeys().iterator().next();
    if (selKey.isValid() && selKey.isConnectable()) {
        // Get channel with connection request
        boolean success = socketChannel.finishConnect();
        if (!success) {
            selKey.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

I pass timeout of 30000 (msec, which is 30 sec), but select returns immediately with selres equal to 0 (on Desktop Java it's 1). Switching socket to blocking mode works fine (so addresses, ports and other stuff is ok).

Ok, I left connection to be blocking (for now). But now my Accept stopped working - Selector doesn't report incoming connections. Again, getting rid of Selector by using a blocking socket works.

So the question is -- does Selector work at all in Android or the code should be rewritten to avoid Selector and java.nio altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has a weird solution found in seemingly unrelated bug-report in Android bug tracker. Android Emulator doesn't support IPv6 and while I don't pretend to request IPv6, it seems that by default Selector attempts to work on IPv6 stack.

Once the following lines are added, my code starts to work correctly:

```
java.lang.System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
java.lang.System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "false");
```

Comment: I will buy you a beer. I will buy you a package of beers! I have been debugging my android app for whole day. It works on all networks, but not on my mother's ISP. I have tried everything! Been thinking whole day about it, testing from all sides, but never could have I thought it might be the IPV6 not being used by ISP. I am still confused as to how can this be. Anyway, adding these two lines solved the issue. Messages pass!

Answer (score 6):

> The following code works on Java

This code has major problems on any platform.

1. You aren't clearing the `selectedKeySet`. Normally this is done by iterating over it and calling `Iterator.remove()`, but in this case you should call `selectedKeys().clear()` as you aren't doing that, although you really should be: see below.
2. You shouldn't register with interestOps=validOps(). You should register `OP_CONNECT` until `finishConnect()` returns true, and thereafter either `OP_READ` or `OP_WRITE`, depending on what you want to do next.
3. If the connection doesn't succeed, `finishConnect()` throws an `IOException`, on which you should close the channel. You aren't doing that.
4. If the connection hasn't finished yet, `finishConnect()` returns false, in which case you should just keep selecting. It doesn't make any sense to cancel the key at that point.
5. If `selres > 1` you aren't processing any selected keys at all. The test should be `if (selRes > 0)`, and it isn't really necessary, as iterating over the `selectedKeySet` will just iterate zero times; however `selRes == 0` does indicate that `select()` timed out, which can be useful if you want to consider timeouts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Since the code is not mine, and selectors are designed in some perverted way, it's not easy to understand the code. However, all your remarks are applicable to code which is never executed simply because selRes == 0 *immediately*. Even if I replace timeout with 0 (which supposedly means "wait infinitely", the code returns immediately. And yes, I tried using OP_CONNECT instead of validOps() - didn't help. Also, this code has been working for years on desktop.

Comment: I've posted solution in my own answer.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp It really doesn't matter who wrote the code. It is *the code* that is 'designed in some perverted way' in this instance, and it needs to be *fixed* so as to conform to the API specification: whether or not it addresses this specific problem is another issue entirely.

Comment: EJP your comment is irrelevant to the real problem which was needed to be addressed in the first place.